# How to make uiviewcontoller display from appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

i am working on an app with uitabbarcontoller(with 5 uiviewcontrollers) and uinavigation bar. 
I have created all of these in the app but when i run it, it doesn't work

This is the AppDelegate.m class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    HomePageView *viewController = [[HomePageView alloc] init];
    FeedViewController *feedViewController=[[FeedViewController alloc]init];
    ProfileViewController *profileViewController=[[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
    PlayViewController *playViewController = [[PlayViewController alloc]init];
    ListeningSessionViewController *listeningSessionViewController= [[ListeningSessionViewController alloc]init];
    RecievedViewController *recievedViewController =[[RecievedViewController alloc]init];

    tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:feedViewController,profileViewController,playViewController,listeningSessionViewController,recievedViewController, nil];

    //navigating to the UITabBarController that you created
    [navCon pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
    [navCon pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why are you pushing the tab bar controller onto the nav controller? Each tab should have its own nav controller as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy I removed that line but it's not still working

Comment: The words "doesn't work" are the most useless words a developer can use. It is meaningless. Please update your question with details about what you want to happen and explain what is actually happening. Be specific.

Comment: I don't see you adding the tabBarController to the window anywhere. Try replacing the last two lines before `return YES` with `self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabC;
```

in **.m** in `appDidFinish`

```
// Initialize window
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

// Initialize your five tab controllers.  with each tab has its own navigation controller
FeedViewController *feedViewController=[[FeedViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:feedViewController];

ProfileViewController *profileViewController=[[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];

PlayViewController *playViewController = [[PlayViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:playViewController];

ListeningSessionViewController *listeningSessionViewController= [[ListeningSessionViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listeningSessionViewController];

RecievedViewController *recievedViewController =[[RecievedViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav5 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:recievedViewController];

// initialize tabbarcontroller and set your viewcontrollers.
self.tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self.tabC.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5, nil];

// Inititalize Navigationcontroller and set root as tabbar.
self.navC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabC];

// Set Window rootview as navigation.
self.window.rootViewController = self.navC;

// Show window
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Is there anyway i can make the tabbar items all show at once ? Because after i set all items, when i run only the first item title shows up. So for other tabbaritems to appear, i literally have to click on each tab to see the title below it.

Comment: so how about apps that have all tabbaritems listed ? you dont have to click each tab before it shows you the title below it, it already exists when the app in first loaded. Do you get what i mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate a `UITabBarController` in `Main.storyBoard` and connect it to the class `tabBarCon` in the identity inspector.

Interface:

```
@interface tabBarCon: UITabBarController

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation tabBarCon

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   HomePageView *viewController = [[HomePageView alloc] init];
   FeedViewController *feedViewController=[[FeedViewController alloc]init];
   ProfileViewController *profileViewController=[[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
   PlayViewController *playViewController = [[PlayViewController alloc]init];
   ListeningSessionViewController *listeningSessionViewController= [[ListeningSessionViewController alloc]init];
   RecievedViewController *recievedViewController =[[RecievedViewController alloc]init];


        NSArray *viewControllerArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:viewController,
                                                                       feedViewController,
                                                                       profileViewController,
                                                                       playViewController,
                                                                       listeningSessionViewController,
                                                                        recievedViewController,nil];

//Then add buttons
 UITabBarItem *moreItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:0];
 viewController.tabBarItem = moreItem;
//...


 self.viewControllers = viewControllerArray;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```